# Choosing between the quickfix with .net wrapper version or quickfix/n version?

Tags: c#, quickfix

I am trying to decide which version to use and would appreciate any feedback on this topic. It would be good to get some pro's and con's.

The research I have done so far would be that the quickfix/n version would run faster and is maybe easier to implement but there does seem to be some functionality that the quickfix/n version does not support i.e. Database support for storing messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment we are using in a production environment a service based on QuickFix with .net wrapper.
We haven't any problem about performances and it's very easy to implement. And a great functionality is the possibility to store messages and logs in a database (we use sqlserver).

I've tested the /n version but at the moment I'm waiting for the switch.
In my opinion the database support in a great feature.

So start implementing the .net wrapper solution!

Best regards, stex

**EDITED**

If you need some surces for sample code, try also:

http://old.nabble.com/QuickFIX-f1039.html

and the official FIX forum:

http://fixprotocol.org/discuss/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought the same thing with the DB support in the wrapper version. Just one other thing, when you say you have tested the /n version but you are waiting for the switch. What do you mean about that?

Comment: Hi ScottS, at the moment we think that the DB support is mandatory in our environment. We will move to the native /n version only when this support will be released. As stated before, we haven't any performance problems. Also the implementation was very straightforward. Overall, I can confirm that the QuickFIX is a great library. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to contact me. Regs, stex

Comment: Thank you for the advise Stex, I agree DB support is important for us too. Do you know when they plan to implement DB support for the /n version?

Comment: Hi ScottS, at the moment I haven't information about the DB support implementation. Best regards, and have a good day. Stex. Please note the links I've posted in my original answer.